# Collection object creation using Generics

Tags: collections, java

When I try to create object as below  :

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

What is wrong syntactically, can any one explain me?

Answer (score 20):

Generics are not co-variant. You can use:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>();
^                                                                ^
--------------^------------------- becomes ------^               |
              -----------------must remain as type ---------------
```

While the `Map` on the outer left hand side of the assignment can "become" a `HashMap` as assigned, the same cannot be applied to any types that appear as generic parameters.

Edit:

As noted by @Keppil, you can use the bounded wildcard syntax:

```
Map<Integer, ? extends Map<String, Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

Note that this syntax will not allow entries to be added to the map but is useful as a type to be passed to and from methods.

Some references:

- [Covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)
- [Generics Gotchas](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html)
- [Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: You can also use `Map<Integer, ? extends Map<String, Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>>();`

Answer (score 10):

It is similar error like

```
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

Parameterized type should be of same type at both end. There is no inheritance (IS-A) concept. If you still want to use it then use wildcard(?) with extend/super keyword which is allowed only at left side of the equals sign.

```
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Dog>(); // is not allowed
```

but

```
Animal[] animal = new Dog[10];  //is allowed
animal[0] = new Dog(); // is allowed
```

where it will later fail and throw exception if somebody tries to add `Cat` (extends Animal) object.

```
animal[1] = new Cat();  //compiles fine but throws java.lang.ArrayStoreException at Runtime.
```

Remember *`animal[1]`* or *`animal[index]`* is holding `reference` of Dog. So `Dog` reference variable can refer to `Dog` object not `Cat` object.

So to avoid such scenario, JSL have made such changes in generics list/Collection. This answer is also applicable for your question(`Map`). 
Parameterized type should be of same type at both end.

```
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
Map<Integer, ? extends Map<String, Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

It is easer to explain on a simpler example

```
Set<Number> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

is not allowed, because then you could add a Double to HashSet of Integers

```
set.add(1.0)
```

Note that

```
Set<? extends Number> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

does not allow to add anything but `null` to the set. But you can only read Numbers from it

You can find more info here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 3):

you need something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>();
myMap.put(1, new HashMap<String, Integer>());
```

Answer (score 3):

`Map<String, Integer>` is not same as `HashMap<String, Integer>`. Thats the problem.

Actually HashMap implements Map interface. So it should be `? extends Map<String, Integer>` on left hand side

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Map<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```